# Regex URL in django

Tags: django, django-urls

Maybe this question is repeat it but I cant find an appropriate answer for my specific issue. I have two URL's:

```
url(r'^dashboard/completar-perfil/(?P<pk>[-_\w]+)/$', CompleteProfileView.as_view()),       

url(r'^dashboard/.*$', DashboardView.as_view()),
```

As you can see both begin with `dashboard`. Problem is the first one does not render CompleteProfileView, always renders DashboardView, if I remove dashboard/ from the first URL, it does work fine, how can I achieve that both urls render each of their respective views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `^dashboard/.*$` is a greedy regular expression that will match everything that start with `dashbord/`, including `dashboard/completar-perfil/`.

So, you may need specify better the second regex. Do you really need .* ?

If it is the index of your dashboard, you could use `^dashboard/$`. Otherwise, you could put another word between dashboard and your greedy regex, like the following:

```
r"^dashboard/another-word/.*$"
```